# Build chromium for raspberrypi2 on wayland with yocto project brings error related to egl.pc and wayland-egl.pc

Tags: chromium, raspberry-pi2, yocto, wayland

I have completed building qt5 on raspberrypi2 by following the instruction here: http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-yocto-parte-1/ 
My next goal is to build chromium with wayland and egl. I have added one more layer from "https://github.com/OSSystems/meta-browser".

Actually, I could successfully build chromium with x11 but still failing with wayland. The things I did for wayland is to add "wayland" with DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " wayland" and remove x11 with DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11".

However, this yields errors and the error messages mentions that missing "egl.pc" and "wayland-egl.pc". Should I add some more components in "DEPENDS" section which will be pre built and create those two package config files in addition to those components in chromium.inc? The build configurations and error messages shown are below.

> Build Configuration:
>   BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
>   BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
>   NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
>   TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
>   MACHINE           = "raspberrypi2"
>   DISTRO            = "poky"
>   DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.8"
>   TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard vfpv4 cortexa7"
>   TARGET_FPU        = "vfp-vfpv4-neon"
>   meta-embarcados
>   meta-rpi          = "fido:dfb2e27bf26b109fc6ccb3bc91924fb3bb24f655"
>   meta-qt5          = "fido:fc026381545650e10fdd488d5b2a3b2d78f87793"
>   meta-raspberrypi  = "fido:b896a7da70dd7a16ba7ffd664f7747cb37e1d142"
>   meta-oe
>   meta-ruby
>   meta-gnome        = "fido:10d3c8f85280a0bf867a8e4f84bcda81c290d28e"
>   meta
>   meta-yocto        = "fido:cd2c9acdbd75c83790e8144d2a834f5b5de35df0"
>   meta-browser      = "master:ca96f4326345dcd779fc539877a04f069f431749"
>
> NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
>   NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
>   NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
>   ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/paul/yocto/build-browser-fido/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/chromium/40.0.2214.91-r0/temp/log.do_configure.13805)
>   ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/paul/yocto/build-browser-fido/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/chromium/40.0.2214.91-r0/temp/log.do_configure.13805
>
> Updating projects from gyp files...
>   Package xcb-shm was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xcb-shm.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   Package 'xcb-shm', required by 'cairo', not found
>   gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --cflags pangocairo pangoft2' returned exit status 1.
>   Requested 'egl >= 9.1.3' but version of egl is 0.0
>   Package wayland-egl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing`wayland-egl.pc'
>   to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'wayland-egl' found
>   gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --cflags "egl >= 9.1.3" "wayland-client >= 1.4.0" >>

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please use SO post edition feature to improve readibility of your post (you can see how to add line breaks at the right of screen). Currently your post is hard and uncomfortable to read. Thanks

Comment: Your post is tagged `chromium-embedded` are you actually using the `Chromium Embedded Project` from which that tag originates?

Comment: @AFract I editied a bit to improve readability. what about now? Thanks.

Comment: @amaitland, I copied chromium from meta-browser as the link in the question. removed chromium-embedded to reduce confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I should have not done DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11". However, I`m still attempting to launch chromium based on wayland compositor.